# How to find the point coordinates on the object's surface for simulate effect like hit on wall from laser beam

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, constraints

I tried using bones constraint (like shrinkwrap ), but doesn't happy.
maybe with script
any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the doc about bvhtree here https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/mathutils.bvhtree.html?highlight=raycast. The last function "ray_cast" can give you the hit point (location, normal, face index and distance)

Comment: Would also suggest looking into [dynamic paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BVH tree and raycasting, as suggested by lemon, in Animation Nodes.

[image]

Comment: Wow! You made my day...
Very good solution

Thanks a lot